# How to code a function in Haskell which takes every other digit from an Int and adds it to a result Int?

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function as mentioned in the title. The specific is that it adds the digits in reversed order, you can see that in the test cases: 12 -> 1; 852369 -> 628; 1714 -> 11; 12345 -> 42; 891 -> 9; 448575 -> 784; 4214 -> 14

The main idea is that when the number is bigger than 99 it enters the helper function which has i - indicator if the the digit is on an even position, and res which stores the result. Helper begins to cycle n as it checks whether or not the current digit is on even position and adds it to the result.

So far I've tried the following code:

```
everyOther :: Int -> Int
everyOther n
  | n < 10 = error "n must be bigger than 10 or equal"
  | n < 100 = div n 10
  | otherwise = helper n 0 0
  where
      helper :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
      helper n i res
        | n < 100 = res
        | i == 1 = helper (div n 10) (i - 1) (res + (mod n 10)*10)
        | otherwise = helper (div n 10) i res
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Comment: It can't properly calculate for >99 numbers

Comment: It doesn't work I've already tried it

Comment: It's a good idea to try splitting up any task in easily understandable and testable parts. Get all the digits -> discard every other one -> sum them up. (Besides: what an _utterly silly_ task that is...)

Comment: I don't want to complete this homework problem, but I would first do a `show` on the number and then deal with the resulting list of digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the one but last digit of `x` with `mod (div x 10) 10`. You can use this with an accumulator that accumulates the value by each time multiplying with 10, so:

```
everyOther :: Int -> Int
everyOther = go 0
    where go a v
              | v < 10 = a
              | otherwise = go (10*a + mod (div v 10) 10) (div v 100)
```

If `v` is thus less than 10, we can return the accumulator, since there is no "other digit" anymore. If that is not the case, we multiply `a` with `10`, and add `mod (div v 10) 10` to add the other digit to it, and recurse with the value divided by 100 to move it two places to the right.

We can improve this, as [@Daniel Wagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71436572/how-to-code-a-function-in-haskell-which-takes-every-other-digit-from-an-int-and#comment126273119_71437569), by making use of [**`quotRem :: Integral a => a -> a -> (a, a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quotRem):

```
everyOther :: Int -> Int
everyOther = go 0
    where go a v
              | v < 10 = a
              | otherwise = let (q, r) = v `quotRem` 100 in go (10*a + r `quot` 10) q
```

here we thus work with the remainder of a division by 100, and this thus avoids an extra modulo.

Comment: This can be made marginally faster by using `quot`/`rem` and by doing one fewer division: ```otherwise = let (q, r) = v `quotRem` 100 in go (10*a + r`quot`10) q```.